# How to use structured query arguments for GROUP BY query using ContentResolver

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-11

In android 30 it is recommended to use structured query arguments.
I want to use [QUERY_ARG_SQL_GROUP_BY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#QUERY_ARG_SQL_GROUP_BY) with `ContentResolver` but its not working.

I am running following query to fetch data rows with `MIMETYPE` equal to `ntactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE` or `ntactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`.

In data table if contact has email and phone number we get two rows with same `CONTACT_ID`.
Now I want to use Group BY `CONTACT_ID` and its not working.
Selection and sorting is working as expected but group by is not working I have to write for loop to remove rows with same `CONTACT_ID`.

```
    val projection =
      arrayOf(
        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID,
        ContactsContract.Data.DATA1,
        ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME
      )

    val selectQuery =
      """
        ${ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE} IN (
        '${ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}',
        '${ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}'
         )
      """.trimIndent()

    val sortOrder =
      """
        ${ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME} GLOB '[A-Za-z]*' DESC,
        LTRIM(LTRIM(${ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME}, '.'), '_')
        COLLATE NOCASE
        """
    val bundle = Bundle().apply {
      putString(ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_SQL_SELECTION, selectQuery)
      putString(ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_SQL_SORT_ORDER, sortOrder)
      // This is not working.
      putString(ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_SQL_GROUP_BY, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID)
    }
    
    context.contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, bundle, null)
```

Comment: "In android 30 it is recommended to use structured query arguments" -- what do you mean by this? Bear in mind that `ContentProvider` is merely an API, and there is no requirement for any provider to honor full SQL syntax. A `ContentProvider` does not have to be backed by SQLite or any other SQL database.

Comment: Yes. Correct but I am fetching data from `Data` table you can see supported operations using SQLite formatting.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data#operations

Comment: As I said apart from GROUP BY everything else is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` clause should be before the `ORDER BY` clause

So try

```
  putString(ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_SQL_SELECTION, selectQuery)
  putString(ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_SQL_GROUP_BY, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID)
  putString(ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_SQL_SORT_ORDER, sortOrder)
```

See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

Comment: Is the order of calling the method putString really how the internal builder creates the final SQL string? That would be very strange. Do you have a source by any chance? If so, thank you!